# Forward abstract unix socket over SSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding, unix-sockets

I've discovered that [OpenSSH is capable of forwarding UNIX sockets](https://lwn.net/Articles/609321/) like this:

```
ssh -R /var/run/program.sock:/var/run/program.sock
```

My question is whether this extends to *abstract unix sockets* too.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
ssh -nNT -R @laminar:@laminar
ssh -nNT -R unix-abstract:laminar:unix-abstract:laminar
```

The program in question does support file-based unix sockets, but as it uses abstract sockets by default I'd like to avoid reconfiguring it to simplify matters if possible.

- OpenSSH (client) version: `OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u4, OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018`
- OpenSSH (server) version: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`

Comment: `socat` supports abstract sockets. Perhaps you could use it as an intermediate.

Comment: Not directly, but with `socat` you can. You can find same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016346/forward-unix-datagram-sockets-with-ssh  (and they are not "abstract" unix sockets, just unix sockets like you have UDP or TCP ones...)

Comment: Good ideas, @meuh / @Patrick Mevzek! I think it's easier to reconfigure said program in this instance to use a file-based socket instead, but I'll keep `socat` in mind for the future :-)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek if `socat` wasn't [ASSuming](https://repo.or.cz/socat.git/blob/cef0e039a89fe3b38e36090d9fe4be000973e0be:/xio-unix.c#l86) that abstract unix socket addresses cannot contain NULs  -- that would be great. **YUCK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with the standard openssh-portable.

You can look for instance at the `unix_listener()` function [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/cac302a4b42a988e54d32eb254b29b79b648dbf5/misc.c#L1569).

Maybe there are patches floating around, but I'm not going to answer with google search results ;-)

Adding such a thing should be technically easy, but who's going to deal with the "political" part, ie. convince the openssh developers to include the patch?

FWIW, such a patch should necessarily check the peer credentials of the clients connecting to the socket by default; openssh already includes the necessary [compat code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/cac302a4b42a988e54d32eb254b29b79b648dbf5/openbsd-compat/bsd-getpeereid.c#L26) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I suspected as much. I'll look at refactoring to use a file-based unix socket instead then. I don't think I've got the skills to add support myself (let alone convince some developers I've never met to include my patch!), so perhaps someone take up the task eventually.